# Why does promise log data but returns undefined with same data

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nativescript

I have a function:

```
getCoordinates: function() {
        geoLocation.getCurrentLocation().then(function(location) {
            return "latitude: " + location.latitude + " longitude:" + location.longitude;
        });
    }
```

Which returns undefined, but when I instead do:

```
getCoordinates: function() {
        geoLocation.getCurrentLocation().then(function(location) {
            console.log("latitude: " + location.latitude + " longitude:" + location.longitude);
        });
    }
```

and run the same function I get:

"latitude: 4X.XXXXXX longitude:-12X.XXXXXXX"

I don't understand why it is returning undefined when the data must be defined or it wouldn't log to the console. Is this some kind of timing issue? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you expect it to return the data, or a promise for the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only `return`ing from the `then` callback, not from the `getCoordinates` function (which in fact doesn't `return` anything, hence `undefined`).

[This is unsolvable for asynchronous callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) in general. In your case, the best solution will be to simply return the promise that you are already creating and which will fulfill with the value you expect in the future.

```
getCoordinates: function() {
    return geoLocation.getCurrentLocation().then(function(location) {
//  ^^^^^^
        return "latitude: " + location.latitude + " longitude:" + location.longitude;
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried the solution you present above. When I do that the promise object itself is returned: [object Promise]

Comment: Yes, that's expected. You cannot return the data, as it doesn't exist yet. Please read the linked question.

Comment: Instead of doing `console.log(getCoordinates())`, you'll need to do `getCoordinates().then(console.log)`, and deal with the fact that you don't get the log immediately.

Comment: OK I understand the problem now. Thanks buddy!